# There is this unwanted space between my footer and main content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been stuck on this issue for hours and hours at this point. I've been trying to work through it on my own but I am just unable to figure it out. Someone save me!

**Problem**: Initially the problem was that my footer wouldn't stick to the bottom of the page, so I followed this popular YouTuber's tutorial on how to fix it using flex. Here's the vid: [Easy sticky footer - stop a footer from floating up a short page!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yc2olxLgKLk&list=LL&index=1). This caused a new issue to arise, now there is this extra white space between my footer and the main content which I think is due to the "margin-top: auto" I added to the footer per the tutorial. This issue isn't apparent in the mobile view of my page but as I expand the page, the main content rises to the top.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "sec1" "sec2" "sec3" "sec4";
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

button {
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  width: 77px;
  height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

button:hover {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: double;
  border-color: rgb(255, 114, 114);
}

.header__text {
  font-size: 17.4px;
}

.header__text span {
  font-size: 0.6em;
}

h3:first-of-type {
  font-size: 8.22px;
  color: #908B87;
}

h3:last-of-type {
  font-size: 9.35px;
  margin-top: 1.3em;
}

.header__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url("../images/nycforheader.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: 40%;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 88px;
  min-height: 12.6vh;
}

.headertext__grouped {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.navbar__menu {
  display: block;
  border-top: solid #908B87 1.15px;
  border-bottom: solid #908B87 1.15px;
}

#navbar__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 50%;
}

#navbar__list li {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 6.02px;
}

#navbar__list li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

#navbar__list li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline red;
  text-underline-offset: 100%;
}

.landing__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: #000000;
}

.landing__container h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.62px;
}

.landing__container p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 9px;
}

#section1 {
  grid-area: sec1;
}

.section2 {
  grid-area: sec2;
}

.section3 {
  grid-area: sec3;
}

.section4 {
  grid-area: sec4;
}

.your-active-class,
.section3 {
  padding: 14px 0 14px 14px;
  background: radial-gradient(100% 100% at 50% 0%, rgba(233, 211, 160, 0.65) 28.12%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 25%);
}

.section2,
.section4 {
  padding: 14px 14px 14px 0;
  background: radial-gradient(100% 100% at 50% 0%, rgba(212, 168, 138, 0.65) 28.12%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 25%);
}

.section2,
.section4 {
  text-align: right;
}

#s2_button,
#s4_button {
  text-align: right;
}

#s2_button button {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('../images/time-square.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#section3 {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('../images/nyc-hotel.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#s4_button button {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('../images/statue-liberty.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position-y: 21%;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 9vh;
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: #908B87;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.footer__list {
  line-height: 10%;
}

.footer__list li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 8.02px;
  margin-inline: 8px;
}

.social__icons {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-inline: 8px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #ffffffcc;
}


/* tablet design */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .header__text {
    font-size: 25.4px;
  }
  h3:first-of-type {
    font-size: 12.22px;
    color: #908B87;
  }
  h3:last-of-type {
    font-size: 12.35px;
    margin-top: 1.3em;
  }
  .header__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 99px;
    min-height: 12.6vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="page__header">
  <div class="header__wrapper">
    <div class="headertext__grouped">
      <h1 class="header__text">New York City <span>Travel Guide</span></h1>
      <h3>USA</h3>
      <h3>#1 in Best Places to Visit In NYC</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar__menu">
    <ul id="navbar__list">

    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="main__wrapper">
  <main>
    <section id="section1" data-nav="Section 1" class="your-active-class">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Why Go To New York City</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pulvinar interdum ipsum, vel ullamcorper arcu volutpat id. Nullam vel lorem vitae eros tempus aliquam. Nunc at ante non neque vestibulum sagittis. Etiam lobortis massa vitae quam
          eleifend lobortis. Nam non ligula at arcu volutpat fringilla vel iaculis quam. Vivamus non orci nec justo accumsan consectetur. Donec egestas arcu non ligula blandit suscipit. Aenean fermentum ex ac nisi porta iaculis. Ut dapibus eros at quam
          semper aliquam sit amet quis massa. Duis in velit eget risus commodo convallis. Sed at lorem a nibh pulvinar viverra. Aenean varius sed dolor pretium condimentum.</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section2" data-nav="Section 2">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>32 Best Things To Do in New York City</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pulvinar interdum ipsum, vel ullamcorper arcu volutpat id. Nullam vel lorem vitae eros tempus aliquam. Nunc at ante non neque vestibulum sagittis. Etiam lobortis massa vitae quam
          eleifend lobortis. Nam non ligula at arcu volutpat fringilla vel iaculis quam. Vivamus non orci nec justo accumsan consectetur. Donec egestas arcu non ligula blandit suscipit. Aenean fermentum ex ac nisi porta iaculis. Ut dapibus eros at quam
          semper aliquam sit amet quis massa.</p>
        <div id="s2_button">
          <a href="#"><button type="button">Click To View</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section3" data-nav="Section 3">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>Best Hotels in New York City</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pulvinar interdum ipsum, vel ullamcorper arcu volutpat id. Nullam vel lorem vitae eros tempus aliquam. Nunc at ante non neque vestibulum sagittis. Etiam lobortis massa vitae quam
          eleifend lobortis. Nam non ligula at arcu volutpat fringilla vel iaculis quam. Vivamus non orci nec justo accumsan consectetur. Donec egestas arcu non ligula blandit suscipit. Aenean fermentum ex ac nisi porta iaculis. Ut dapibus eros at quam
          semper aliquam sit amet quis massa.</p>
        <a href="#"><button id="section3" type="button">Click To View</button></a>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section4" data-nav="Section 4">
      <div class="landing__container">
        <h2>What to Eat in New York City</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pulvinar interdum ipsum, vel ullamcorper arcu volutpat id. Nullam vel lorem vitae eros tempus aliquam. Nunc at ante non neque vestibulum sagittis. Etiam lobortis massa vitae quam
          eleifend lobortis. Nam non ligula at arcu volutpat fringilla vel iaculis quam. Vivamus non orci nec justo accumsan consectetur. Donec egestas arcu non ligula blandit suscipit. Aenean fermentum ex ac nisi porta iaculis. Ut dapibus eros at quam
          semper aliquam sit amet quis massa.</p>
        <div id="s4_button">
          <a href="#"><button type="button">Click To View</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</div>
<footer>
  <ul class="footer__list">
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Newsletters</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="social__icons__container">
    <a class="social__icons" href="#">
      <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
    </a>
    <a class="social__icons" href="#">
      <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
</footer>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if setting `display:flex` to `body` is a good idea... You should use a container to allow additional elements to be positioned outside of that `flex` structure. Anyway, the extra space you see above the footer is probably because your screen is large enough to display the entire content, and the footer sits at the bottom. What your code does is align your footer after your content, and if there is extra space, `margin:auto' will cover it, so that the footer remains at the bottom of the screen. Looks like expected behavior.

Comment: do you want to fix your footer at bottom of the page and scroll the content?

Comment: @Will thank you for the feedback! may you please share actionable adjustments that I can make to my code. I understand what you are saying but how can I apply the change you are suggesting.

Comment: Body + Flexbox is common and not a bad approach. However `min-height: 100%` is useless. It should be `min-height: 100vh;`

Comment: @mreynoso9595 You can use a container like `<div class="flex-wrapper">...your content...</div>` and its style would be `.flex-wrapper { display:flex; flex-direction:column; }`. See live demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/xj6gban8/

Comment: @tacoshy Seems like bad practice. Every page of his site will be "flexed". Additonal "non-flex" classes will be needed to disable it in CSS. A container that defines a specific style is much easier to maintain across an entire website. Or you can add a class to `body` to make sure `flex` doesn't apply to the entire website.

Comment: @Will no it is not bad practise and it is a common approach. That allos you to flex-grow the main elemenet and occupy at least 100vh even with less content. `flex-direction: column` ensures a normal block-level flow

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal exactly! unfortunately none of the responses here so far have been very helpful.

Comment: @GulshanAggarwal do you have a solution?

Comment: @mreynoso9595 actually I can help you but the problem is that I'm unable to figure out what you exactly needed?

Answer (score 0):

> Initially the problem was that my footer wouldn't stick to the bottom
> of the page

There are *many* successful approaches to achieving this effect, but one of the simplest, oldest and most broadly supported is to use **absolute positioning** on the `<header>` and `<footer>` and apply `overflow: auto` to the `<main>` element.

In the example below you can delete text from (or add text to) the `<main>` element. You will see that the `<footer>` remains positioned at the bottom of the viewport no matter how much or how little text the `<main>` element contains.

---

**Working Example 1:** *(Run Code Snippet and click Full Page)*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header,
footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(127, 127,  0);
}

main {
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  top: calc(100vh - 100px);
}

h2 {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h2>Header</h2>
</header>

<main contenteditable="true">
<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, “and what is the use of a book,” thought Alice “without pictures or conversations?”</p>

<p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>

<p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, “Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!” (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>

<p>In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.</p>

<p>The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel for some way, and then dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a moment to think about stopping herself before she found herself falling down a very deep well.</p>

<p>Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she had plenty of time as she went down to look about her and to wonder what was going to happen next. First, she tried to look down and make out what she was coming to, but it was too dark to see anything; then she looked at the sides of the well, and noticed that they were filled with cupboards and book-shelves; here and there she saw maps and pictures hung upon pegs. She took down a jar from one of the shelves as she passed; it was labelled “ORANGE MARMALADE”, but to her great disappointment it was empty: she did not like to drop the jar for fear of killing somebody underneath, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards as she fell past it.</p>

<p>“Well!” thought Alice to herself, “after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they’ll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn’t say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!” (Which was very likely true.)</p>

<p>Down, down, down. Would the fall never come to an end? “I wonder how many miles I’ve fallen by this time?” she said aloud. “I must be getting somewhere near the centre of the earth. Let me see: that would be four thousand miles down, I think—” (for, you see, Alice had learnt several things of this sort in her lessons in the schoolroom, and though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her, still it was good practice to say it over) “—yes, that’s about the right distance—but then I wonder what Latitude or Longitude I’ve got to?” (Alice had no idea what Latitude was, or Longitude either, but thought they were nice grand words to say.)</p>

<p>Presently she began again. “I wonder if I shall fall right through the earth! How funny it’ll seem to come out among the people that walk with their heads downward! The Antipathies, I think—” (she was rather glad there was no one listening, this time, as it didn’t sound at all the right word) “—but I shall have to ask them what the name of the country is, you know. Please, Ma’am, is this New Zealand or Australia?” (and she tried to curtsey as she spoke—fancy curtseying as you’re falling through the air! Do you think you could manage it?) “And what an ignorant little girl she’ll think me for asking! No, it’ll never do to ask: perhaps I shall see it written up somewhere.”</p>
</main>

<footer>
<h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
```

---

Alternatively, you can tweak the setup above very slightly to build a display which no longer has an absolutely positioned `<footer>`.

**Working Example 2:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header,
footer {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(127, 127,  0);
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 0 18px;
  overflow: auto;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
<h2>Header</h2>
</header>

<main contenteditable="true">
<p>Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it, “and what is the use of a book,” thought Alice “without pictures or conversations?”</p>

<p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by her.</p>

<p>There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, “Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!” (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>

<p>In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how in the world she was to get out again.</p>

<p>The rabbit-hole went straight on like a tunnel for some way, and then dipped suddenly down, so suddenly that Alice had not a moment to think about stopping herself before she found herself falling down a very deep well.</p>

<p>Either the well was very deep, or she fell very slowly, for she had plenty of time as she went down to look about her and to wonder what was going to happen next. First, she tried to look down and make out what she was coming to, but it was too dark to see anything; then she looked at the sides of the well, and noticed that they were filled with cupboards and book-shelves; here and there she saw maps and pictures hung upon pegs. She took down a jar from one of the shelves as she passed; it was labelled “ORANGE MARMALADE”, but to her great disappointment it was empty: she did not like to drop the jar for fear of killing somebody underneath, so managed to put it into one of the cupboards as she fell past it.</p>

<p>“Well!” thought Alice to herself, “after such a fall as this, I shall think nothing of tumbling down stairs! How brave they’ll all think me at home! Why, I wouldn’t say anything about it, even if I fell off the top of the house!” (Which was very likely true.)</p>

<p>Down, down, down. Would the fall never come to an end? “I wonder how many miles I’ve fallen by this time?” she said aloud. “I must be getting somewhere near the centre of the earth. Let me see: that would be four thousand miles down, I think—” (for, you see, Alice had learnt several things of this sort in her lessons in the schoolroom, and though this was not a very good opportunity for showing off her knowledge, as there was no one to listen to her, still it was good practice to say it over) “—yes, that’s about the right distance—but then I wonder what Latitude or Longitude I’ve got to?” (Alice had no idea what Latitude was, or Longitude either, but thought they were nice grand words to say.)</p>

<p>Presently she began again. “I wonder if I shall fall right through the earth! How funny it’ll seem to come out among the people that walk with their heads downward! The Antipathies, I think—” (she was rather glad there was no one listening, this time, as it didn’t sound at all the right word) “—but I shall have to ask them what the name of the country is, you know. Please, Ma’am, is this New Zealand or Australia?” (and she tried to curtsey as she spoke—fancy curtseying as you’re falling through the air! Do you think you could manage it?) “And what an ignorant little girl she’ll think me for asking! No, it’ll never do to ask: perhaps I shall see it written up somewhere.”</p>
</main>

<footer>
<h2>Footer</h2>
</footer>
```

Comment: thats a very unresponsive solution to calcularte all the height. also requires to have fixed heights to start with

Comment: @tacoshy - What's unresponsive?

Comment: that it only works aslong as the height of the footer and header is pre-set. means espacially for mobile devices where you might wanna change the height or expend the height to fit contents will not work correctly.

Comment: @tacoshy - So we can use `vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, `vmax`, `lh`, `em` or `rem` units or we can use `%` or we can use `@media` queries or we can use `min()`, `max()` or `clamp()` functions. There's twelve options. I'm sure there are more.

Comment: and still all of them require a pre-set heigh both for footer and header in order to calculate the right -minheight for the main content. And thats the reason why it will remain unresponsive.

Comment: All the options I've listed above (_units_, _percentages_, _media queries_, _functions_) are responsive. Deploying responsive values via _custom properties_ means they will be straightforward to maintain. Please can you take five minutes out from lazily attacking my answer and write your own answer so the OP can benefit from your superior wisdom? Thanks.

Comment: its not about the units you sue. it is about the fact that you have to give them a defiend (pre-set)  height. What if you dont know the how heigh the header or footer goign to be? For example because the header wraps into a hamburger layout? That is the unresponsive part not the units. The OP already does it the right way. Just need to change `min-height: 100%` to `min-height: 100vh` and set a `flex-grow: 1` to the main content.

Comment: Okay, you carry on attacking, then. Have a great day, @tacoshy.